# ActiveMQ compositeTopic's selective persistence

Tags: java, jms, persistence, activemq-classic

I'm using ActiveMQ's `compositeTopic` to fan-out messages to multiple destinations like this:

```
<broker>
    <persistenceAdapter>
        <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>

    ...

    <destinationInterceptors>
        <virtualDestinationInterceptor>
            <virtualDestinations>
                <compositeTopic name="fan-out" forwardOnly="true">
                    <forwardTo>
                        <queue physicalName="persistent"/>
                        <queue physicalName="ephemeral"/>
                    </forwardTo>
                </compositeTopic>
            </virtualDestinations>
        </virtualDestinationInterceptor>
    </destinationInterceptors>
</broker>
```

So, I want to forward messages to both `persistent` and `ephemeral` queues at the same time. As you might guess from their names, I want messages in `persistent` queue to be persistent and I do not need persistence for `ephemeral` queue. The problem is that ActiveMQ doesn't have a concept of a persistence on a per destination basis, does it? One can set persistence for a whole broker, or use persistence / non-persistence delivery modes. So, the question is: how can I disable persistence for `ephemeral` queue in this case?

Comment: Based on this [page](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-difference-between-persistent-and-non-persistent-delivery.html), seems like you are correct: "The persistence flag is set on the `MessageProducer` for all messages using the `setDeliveryMode`. It can also be specified on a per message basis using the long form of the send method. Persistence is a property of a an individual message."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the solution that seems to work is to use Apache Camel with ActiveMQ. Just add a route that drains `ephemeral` queue to another queue setting TTL / persistence mode in process:

```
<broker>
    <persistenceAdapter>
        <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>

    ...

    <destinationInterceptors>
        <virtualDestinationInterceptor>
            <virtualDestinations>
                <compositeTopic name="fan-out" forwardOnly="true">
                    <forwardTo>
                        <queue physicalName="persistent"/>
                        <queue physicalName="ephemeral"/>
                    </forwardTo>
                </compositeTopic>
            </virtualDestinations>
        </virtualDestinationInterceptor>
    </destinationInterceptors>
</broker>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="camel">
    <route>
        <from uri="activemq:queue:ephemeral"/>
        <to uri="activemq:queue:ephemeral-backend?timeToLive=10000"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

`timeToLive` is message's TTL in milliseconds. In the config above messages are still persistent: after TTL expires they are moved to [DLQ](http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html). If you want to throw them away then the config should include `deliveryPersistent` set to `false`:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="camel">
  <route>
    <from uri="activemq:queue:ephemeral" />
    <to uri="activemq:queue:ephemeral-backend?timeToLive=10000&amp;deliveryPersistent=false" />
  </route>
</camelContext>
```